# JSON remove key value for particular key name

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON like the following, I am trying to remove "age" from it and rename "name" to "key" and "height" to "value". Can someone please suggest what would be the neatest way to achieve this.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "A",
            "age": 8,
            "height": 120
        },
        {
            "name": "B",
            "age": 18,
            "height": 150
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: what are the ways you are considering?

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't really a place to ask for advice on programming, but more a place to figure out what's wrong.  That being said, I personally would use `map` You can read more about it here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff679976(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: Smeegs: Are you suggesting a question should always be asking "what's wrong". If so I think more than half of the questions on SO should be down voted.

Comment: @Andy897, read into my comment however you want.  I'm the only one who provided any advice.

Comment: @source.rar .. I tried iterating over the JSON and deleting and renaming, it works but it is a mess I think.

Comment: @Andy897 can you show the code you've tried..?

Comment: @webkit: Sure, I am creating a jsfiddle. Thank You!

Comment: @Andy897, I added a fiddle using map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is how you do it using `map` as I mentioned.](http://jsfiddle.net/7Dd7m/)

`map` is exactly what you're looking for, it's a way to create a new array based on an existing array using whatever criteria you want.

```
var json = {
    "data": [{
        "name": "A",
        "age": 8,
        "height": 120
    }, {
        "name": "B",
        "age": 18,
        "height": 150
    }]
};
json.data = json.data.map(function (d) {
    return {
        key: d.name,
        value: d.height
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank You!. . I will try to be more specific going ahead. I was able to get this by iterating over the JSON. I should have said that in the question. I will edit it. Appreciate the patience and help.

Comment: No problem, SO is really fickle with their questions.  I wasn't trying to be snippy, just trying to explain the downvotes.  This site used to be a great place to ask for advice, but the powers that be have moved away from that.  There is http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, but they are just as fickle there.

Comment: I will keep this in mind and make sure I do not contribute in making it worse and work towards improving things here ..however I can in my capacity.

Comment: Yeah, you've gotta take the good with the bad.  Even with all the people who are quick to downvote this place is a such a good resource.